# copyList(List<T> destinationList, List<T> sourceList), why Eclipse does not recognize generic T?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method `copyList(List<T> destinationList, List<T> sourceList)` with T generic type. It mean that the sys only accept if the destinationList & the sourceList have the same type if they don't then the method won't allow.

Ex: `copyList(List<String[]> destinationList, List<String[]> sourceList` or `copyList(List<String[][]> destinationList, List<String[][]> sourceList` are allowed

But `copyList(List<String[][]> destinationList, List<String[]> sourceList` won't be allowed cos they don't have the same type.

However, my eclipse has this error "T can not be resolve as a Type"

Comment: Isn't that what `destinationList.addAll(sourceList)` already does?

Comment: addAll(Collection) not addAll(List)

Comment: yes but `List` is a `Collection` so that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to declare the type parameter either at method level (before return type), or at the class level (after the class name). In this case, it seems it's a generic method, so declare it like this:

```
public <T> void copyList(List<T> destinationList, List<T> sourceList) { }
```

So, the `<T>` before return type is called type parameter declaration. Similarly, if you had to make a class generic, you do it like this:

```
// A generic class
class MyList<T> {

}
```

**Further Read:**

- [Generic Methods - Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)
- [Java Generics FAQs - Angelika Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [Generic Types](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html)
  - [Generic Methods](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html)